# Can't access WP-Admin via HTTPS

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, https

I facing an issue. I installed WordPress on a Ubuntu server.

Though both site_url and home_url are with https, WordPress keeps loading files via http. This blocks me when trying to login (login form action is http too) and also loads assets via http and I get Warnings in browser console. The server is configured by third party and it redirects to https.

I used:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://sitename.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://sitename.com' );
```

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

With these two I receive to many redirects on wp-admin.

---

The only thing that worked (at least to log in) was:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=="/index.php")
{
define('WP_HOME','https://sitename.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://sitename.com');
}
else
{
define('WP_HOME','http://sitename.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://sitename.com');
}
```

But this is not a solution, cause my site will load assets via http... I searched and tested solutions from here and other sites, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` file? Could be worth adding this at the top: 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] `

Comment: Thanks, Tom. The problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

@Tomc 's solution is a great start. Here it is formatted (you can't format things in a comment).

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

In addition, I'm not a fan of setting URLs in the configuration files. Best (IMHO) to set those two values in the wp-options table.

You might need to look at the entire database to ensure that all references to internal assets (especially media) is set to https . There are several plugins that allow you to search (and replace) items in the database - my go-to is the "Better Search and Replace" plugin.

You can use the Developer tools in your browser (usually F12) to see all requests, and find those that are not https.

**Added**

Here's a rewrite rule for forcing SSL, plus WordPress basic. Change domain name to match yours.

```
 RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks, Rick! This is inside my htacces `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`.
The site has SSL, is redirected to https. Even with home and site_url set to https, it loads WordPress assets with http (and gives too many redirects if trying to access wp-admin).

Comment: Have you tried a force refresh from your browser and deleted any cache in caching plugins in Wordpress or host?

Comment: @Alki - try the htaccess in my edited answer. That will get you forced to SSL, plus the basic htaccess that WordPress needs. You may still need to search/replace inside the database, as I previously mentioned. Clearing cache is always a good idea; but you can accomplish that by testing with a private browser session.